# Configuring no_proxy on centOS

Tags: linux, centos, networking, curl, proxy

This issue is on centOS 7.

I configured the proxy address following [this process](https://www.server-world.info/en/note?os=CentOS_7&p=squid&f=2)!, post which the network was working fine.

But, I need few domain sites excluded from proxy. So, I added the following line to /etc/profile.

```
export no_proxy="127.0.0.1, localhost, *.org.in"
```

Curl to those sites didn't work.

```
[raj@hostname ~]$ curl -sk http://app.org.in/
```

Network Error

> Network Error (dns_unresolved_hostname)
>
>
>
>
>
>
> Your requested host "app.org.in" could not be resolved by DNS.

I tried with --no-proxy argument, and it worked.

```
[raj@hostname ~]$ curl --noproxy "*" -sk http://app.org.in/
```

Could someone please help me in setting the proxy for not acting on the domain websites.

Comment: When you say `*.domain.com`, do you mean `*` as a wildcard (for www, ftp, and all other words), or as a literal asterisk? I'm not even sure the 2nd would even be a proper domain name.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Here 'domain' is our client name(which I am covering up). In the example, I'm trying to access a specific application of the client. All our applications end with the client name at the end(supposedly like mail.google.com, drive.google.com,images.google.com..). I am trying to configure proxy such that it wouldn't apply to the applications on the client domain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved.

I was appending asterisk(*) in the no_proxy ( *.org.in) which caused the issue. The issue is resolved after removing the *.